# How to pack my iphone app into a deb

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cydia, deb

I used xcode to write an iPhone "hello world" app, and I would like to package it as a deb for Cydia.
I have seen [saurik's article on How to Host a Cydia™ Repository](http://www.saurik.com/id/7), but I do not understand this table:

```
+- MyProgram
   +- Applications
   |  +- MyProgram.app
   |     +- Info.plist
   |     +- MyProgram
   |     +- icon.png
```

What does "MyProgram" in MyProgram.app need? Should I copy my "hello world" project folder to it?

How do I run "hello world" as a deb with Cydia?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: good question, as i am currently struggling with this myself

Answer (score 1):

`MyProgram` in in `MyProgram.app` is the actual binary for your application.

`MyProgram.app` is the application bundle.

If you've built from Xcode and used default locations, you'll find this under:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<yourapp>/Build/Products/<configuration>-iphoneos/MyProgram.app
```

Alternatively, if you've packaged the ipa, it's contents below the `Payload` directory of the ipa (a zip file).